# Why is my garage door opening and closing automatically?

Tags: doors

When I open the garage door, then get into my truck, the door closes automatically. If both garage doors are closed and I get into my truck one of the doors will open. The only way to get my truck out of the garage is to unplug the opener. This happens 70 percent of the time. Something is interfering with the opener. Could Bluetooth be the cause?

Comment: Is there an opener lodged in the seat cushions?

Comment: Also, this type of question calls for make and model information. Please revise to add it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Are you using LED or CFL bulbs anywhere near the opener?

Comment: Do you have a model of truck that has onboard intelligence that knows how to signal a garage door opener to open? Back in my day, trucks were simple, but nowadays they have computers and display screens and talking voices.  One of their features is to auto-open the garage door for you.  On many openers, "open" and "close" is the same signal...

Comment: at some times of year, the sun might peak through and confuse the optical obstruction sensors, in which case adding "horse blinders" can help.

Comment: Get a gremlin trap those pesky critters are pushing the button.